# When is Craft 3 ready for commercial use

Tags: craft3

We are  trying out some features of the new Craft update and are wondering how ready for use the current version is and if any of you guys are already using it outside a testing environment.

And if not, is there a clear signal of the development team on when to switch to the newer version?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full release is only 23 days so I would suggest that it's time to start looking: https://craftcms.com/news/craft-3-launch-faq